# How to check captcha using ajax without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have problem when trying to check the captcha with Ajax !
Form

```
<img src="captcha.php" width="100px"/>
<input size="20" id="rand" type="text" name="rand">
```

js

```
$("#rand").keyup(function() {
var rand = $("#rand").val();
if(rand != rand2)
{
        $("#rand").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
        $("#rand").addClass("object_ok");
        $("#status5").html('<img src="tick.gif" align="absmiddle">');
}
else
    {
    $("#status5").html('<font color="red">Wrong Captcha</font>');
    $("#rand").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
    $("#rand").addClass("object_error");
    }
}); //rand
```

How to make if rand != captcha
while captcha in different file !

Comment: What captcha service or plugin are you using?

Comment: here is<?php
session_start();
$string = md5(rand(0,99));
$new_string = substr($string, 17, 6);
$_SESSION['magic']=$new_string;
//imagecreate(width, height) of background
$im = imagecreate(90, 25);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $black);
//imagestring("","", margin-left, margin-top, $string, $string_color)
imagestring($im, 5, 20, 5, $new_string, $white);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>

Comment: Long segments of code do not belong in the comments. It's difficult for anyone to make sense of the code. Could you post it as an update in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a captcha check on the client-side. You do need a server-side script that would do the check for you. You would then need to use `ajax` to call that server-side script with user-data and other encrypted data need to do the verification on the server-side.

An ajax call would look something like this:

```
$.post( 'captcha-verifier.php', <user+captcha-data> ).done(function(data) {
    //check 'data' for verification result
    //decide next step
});
```

This piece of code would need to be included in an event handler that's triggered when the user indicates that they have completed entering their input, such as a button click. Example:

```
$(function() {
    $('.some-button').on('click', function() {
        //gather data for ajax call if necessary
        //make ajax call above
    });
});
```

Comment: a captha must be done client side, otherwise the user couldn't see it.